# Are there any non-repeatable IEnumerable classes?

Tags: .net, ienumerable

Are there any non-repeatable IEnumerable classes?

By non-repeatable I mean where you can't safely call GetEnumerator multiple times or where calling GetEnumerator has observable side effects.

Comment: What do you mean by non-repeatable? Based on the two answers your question is ambiguous.

Comment: Enumerators are not necessarily repeatable. If your enumerators wraps a stream, then you can't necessarily call Reset on it. But going up one level, you can generally call GetEnumerator as many times are you like and always get the same result. But can you always call GetEnumerator that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.ReadLines()` does return an `IEnumerable<T>` that only works once.

Comment: Well that's a nasty surprise waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug in the library. That it doesn't throw a normal `InvalidOperationException` but passes the error that comes from accessing a disposed textreader through to the caller hints that it might really be a bug.

Comment: This was probably a bug (or a feature) in .NET 4.0. I can't reproduce it with .NET 4.5.

Comment: [Bug in the File.ReadLines(..) method of the .net framework 4.0](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535097/bug-in-the-file-readlines-method-of-the-net-framework-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for implementations of IEnumerable(Of T) to return any items they see fit, for any reason whatsoever.  It's pretty well expected that if one calls GetEnumerator twice on the same sequence of items, and then proceeds to cycle through both enumerators, they should either yield the same items in the same order or throw an exception.  There are a number of routines that accept an IEnumerable(Of T) and will fail badly if given one that does not abide by such a contract.

If I had my druthers, IEnumerable would have been split into a family of interfaces; the basic IEnumerable's enumerator would lose the Reset method and would convey no particular promise of repeatability.  A new IMultiEnumerable would return an enumerator with a Reset method and and a guarantee that multiple passes would yield identical data; the enumerator might also support its own GetEnumerator method (I think that should be practical for any type which could support multi-pass enumeration; the only cost would be a 'start' pointer so the nested enumerator would be reset to the location of its original creation).

Answer (score 0):

No, any well behaving class that implements `IEnumerable` will allow repeated enumerations.

To enumerate collections that aren't repeatable, you don't have a class that implements `IEnumerable`. Instead you have a method that returns an enumerator. That way the enumerator instead of a class holds the collection, so it's not possible to call `GetEnumerator` twice for the same collection. To repeat the enumerator you have to call the method to create a new collection.

An example of this is the `Enumerable.Range` method. It creates the items for a range on the fly, so the range doesn't exist as a collection, which makes it non-repeatable. To enumerate the same range again you call the method to create a new range with the same bounds.

Comment: Enumerable.Range doesn't create the items at all, that is taken care of by Enumerable.Range.GetEnumerator. Since the enumerator it returns has the same intital values each time, it still would be considered repeatable.

Comment: @Jonathan: You are missing the point. The range is not repeatable as you can't enumerate the same range again, you have to create a new range. Since the Range method doesn't return an enumerable object but an enumerator, there is no object that you can call GetEnumerator on to repeat the enumeration.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong with the answer, it can't improve it.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong with the answer, it can't improve it.