# C#: Iterator vs function returning IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Let's say a have two methods:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> DoSomething1();
IEnumerable<int> DoSomething2();
```

that modify the state of my object. I don't know if the function uses `yield` inside or just returns a `List<int>`.

And then I'd like to take the output and pass to two other functions:

```cs
void SendToUser(IEnumerable<int> values);
void PrintOut(IEnumerable<int> values);
```

Then just based on the function interface (`DoSomethingX`) I cannot say if this is a valid operation or not:

```cs
var values = DoSomethingX();
SendToUser(values);
PrintOut(values)
```

Because in the case of iterator it will result in calling `DoSomethingX` twice.

Is this some kind of inconsistency or I'm using iterator/`IEnumerable` in the wrong way? Where is the problem?

Comment: when `SendToUser` exhausts the `IEnumerable`, then there won't be anything left for `PrintOut`. so you need to reinitialize `values` after the first call has finished, if you expect `PrintOut` to operate on the same sequence.

Comment: Why would it call `DoSomething` twice? The `value` stores a reference to an `IEnumerable`, passing it around would should not trigger any other calls.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface, that's just wrong. have you actually tried this? an enumerable does not get exhausted when passed around, you can iterate over it as many times as you like. IEnumerable does not store some cursor.

Comment: btw, it doesn't smell right to have query methods modifying state.

Comment: usually the stateful part is the `IEnumerator` obtained by calling `GetEnumerator` on the `IEnumerable`. but I'd tread cautiously, the standard does not mandate repeatability. While it certainly should, there are [known cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239258/1132334).

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface ok, that's fugly. i guess that's the reason FXcop or ReSharper show a hint to "materialize" the enumerable if used more than once.

Comment: Play with [this Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/fpogypvw-idlemind) and look closely at the output.

Answer (score 4):

If a method returns `IEnumerable` then you should only rely on the fact that it is iterable, nothing more, as the implementation of that method is subject to change.

If you have control over the method and know that consumers require a more specific type, then return a more specific type.

If you don't have control and need to implement list behaviour, you could always convert the `IEnumerable` into a list:

```
var values = DoSomethingX().ToList();
SendToUser(values);
PrintOut(values);
```

Comment: `you should only rely on the fact that it is iterable`. Isn't it even more: it is iterable **only once**?

Comment: @user2146414 where do you get that notion from? have you actually tried this? you can iterate over it as many times as you wish.

Comment: @user2146414 No, `IEnumerable` provides no such reassurances. That is an implementation detail.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. You can iterate over `IEnumerable` many times.... but if it is an iterator then your code will be called twice. If it is a `List` then only once.

Answer (score 1):

Read about CQS (command query separation): [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)

In short, there are 2 types of methods:

1. commands, e.g. `void DoSomething(string data)` - they change state of your instance
2. queries, e.g `IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(Filter filter)` - which does not change state, they just return some data

Sometimes commands can return value, i.e. `PersonID CreatePerson(...);`

So if you refactor your code to:

```
void DoSomething1();
void DoSomething2();
IEnumerable<int> GetData();
```

it will solve your problem.

The `IEnumerable` type is just an interface that allows you to iterate over some elements. You don't have idea what is inside concrete implementation.
Usually implementation of `IEnumerable` should not have any side effects, i.e. changing state of some objects.

If you are dealing with `IEnumerable` that changes state, you can always materialize it using `.ToList()` LINQ extension. Then you can pass it to any method w/o any extra side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `var values = DoSomethingX();` does not enumerate the collection or iterator it returns.

1. It may return a `List<int>`. In this case the list is assigned to `values`. More precisely: a reference to this list.
2. If `DoSomethingX` is an iterator method, then C# creates an object of an anonymous class implementing `IEnumerable<int>` as a state machine. This object is assigned to `values`.

Therefore there is no difference in usage of these two `IEnumerable<int>`. It does not matter whether it is based on a collection or on a iterator method. Iteration usually starts in a for-each loop or when calling a LINQ method like `ToList` or `ToArray`.

You can iterate manually. First you have to get the enumerator:

```
IEnumerator<int> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
```

Then call the methods of this enumerator:

```
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) { // Enumeration starts here.
    int value = enumerator.Current;
    ...
}
```

---

When you iterate over `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` twice, then of course its code runs twice. If you think that this might be time consuming, e.g. if the iterator queries a database or the file system, then you should call `.ToList()` before calling it twice:

```
var records = QueryDatabaseReturnsIEnumerable().ToList();
SendToUser(records);
PrintOut(records);
```

On the other hand, calling  `.ToList()` when the enumerable is based on a collection, then you perform an unnecessary memory and time consuming copy operation.

Usually you can say from the context, whether this is necessary or not. Otherwise the best you could do, is to test for other interfaces:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = DoSomethingX();
if (!(values is IList<int>) && !(values is ICollection<int>)) {
    values = values.ToList();
}
SendToUser(values);
PrintOut(values);
```

But I doubt that this is a good practice. Interfaces should be consumed without worrying about their implementation. Doing so defies their purpose.

Comment: Yes. I know I can. My problem is that I don't know if I ran the code twice when I iterate over `IEnumerable` twice (or only once - in the case of `List`)